# What is nelnet doing with my auto-debit student loan payments?

Tags: loans, student-loan, repayment

I recently (A few months ago) bumped up my loan repayment. My repayment just started this year.

So, I took a look at how nelnet is allocating my auto debit, and my payment history looks like this:

```
 Date       Payment    Principle  Interest
 05/11/2018 $500.00    $340.05    $159.95 
 04/11/2018 $500.00    $491.90    $8.10  
 03/11/2018 $500.00    $420.77    $79.23     
 02/11/2018 $350.00    $256.31    $93.69
```

Why would the amount allocated to principal and interest fluctuate so much? It seems rather random when looking at how much was allocated to each loan in a more detailed statement.

The month with the low applied interest payment was all thrown to 1 loan and the others are spread out quite a bit.

For more detail, I have around 25k in loans and it is spread across 8 loans with an average interest rate around 4%.

Comment: When did you graduate?  Perhaps one of the loans just ended a zero-interest grace period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your additional payments are being applied to the next month's interest payment first, then to principle, but it's hard to follow exactly without detail, it could be that along with some timing disparity between payments, unless you actually made each payment on the 11th.

If you pay the minimum and then make a 2nd additional payment you should be able to specify that the extra goes to principle on your highest interest loan, or if you can assign portions in your normal payment just make sure to pay the minimum on each loan.

You should call them for explanation if still curious.